# For which $n$, $x^{n - 1} \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}$ is differentiable for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> For a whole number $n$, if $f(x) = x^{n - 1} \sin{\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}\qquad x \ne 0 \qquad \& \qquad f(0) = 0 $, then in order that $n$ is differentiable at all $x$, the value of $n$ will be $\ldots$

How to find $n$?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Such as differentiating $x^{n-1}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\neq 0$ then clearly the function $f$ is differentiable at $x.$
So it is enough to check out for which $n$ the function is differentiable a the point $x=0.$
Thus we have $$f'(0)=\lim_{v\to 0} \frac{f(v) -f(0)}{v} =\lim_{v\to 0} v^{n-2}\sin (v^{-1} )$$
but the last limit exists if and only if $n-2>0.$ So the answer is $n>2.$